# Unable to install Material UI on new React app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've just created a new React app using Create React App. When I went to install Matrial UI, I received the following error message:

[Link to image of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcRre.png)

Other packages are able to be installed just fine. Is this an issue with React 17? Should I rollback to an earier version? I use React and Material UI daily at work, but this was on an app created back in June.

EDIT: I've attempted to delete the node modules folder and re-install, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misspelled the command to install the package.
You put:
npm i npm install @material-ui/core
You should insert:
npm i @material-ui/core
or
npm install @material-ui/core

Comment: That was actually an additional typo from having tried half a dozen different soltuons. I've added a new image without the typo, and you can see the issue persists.

Comment: @BenJones I tried here and this command works fine. I think your nodejs is outdated. Try to update your nodejs and npm

Comment: I'm running v15.0.1, which is the latest version.

Based on the error, and the fact that I can still install other packages into the project, I feel like this is something to do with Material UI and React not getting along.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was caused by the fact that I was using the 'latest' version of Node, that being 15.0.1. I installed the LTS version, currently 12.19.0, and Material UI now installs and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I install it with NPM.
I solved this issues with yarn instead of npm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).